# calculate sum with number fluctuations

Tags: sql-server

I'm calculating water flow and have come across a situation and need help.

```
Date/Time  Account   Read
---------  --------  -----
04:00.0    16887084  38665
03:30.0    16887084  38652 **<< Reverse flow**
03:00.0    16887084  38660
02:30.0    16887084  38656
```

I need to calculate the amount of water usage (as shown in the Read Col), however due to reverse flow, the sample at 03:30 rolled back by 8 gallons and at the next sample had increased by 13 gallons. How can I calculate true water usage? I've tried the following but the statement is basically using number range as a representation of usage:

```
SELECT  serial AS Account,
    max(READ)- min(READ) AS GalsTotal,

    FROM dbo.Database 
WHERE (dbf_DT > DATEADD(HH, -24, getdate()))
```

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Are you saying you would like to toss out the reverse flow reading at 3:30? So the actual useage would be 9 gallons? Also, which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to get the date and time of the last reading within the period, and the date and time of first reading within the period (or of the last reading before the beginning of the period), and then use that to retrieve the rows.

```
SELECT s.serial AS Account
     , MAX(lr.READ) - MIN(fr.READ) AS GalsTotal
  FROM (SELECT d.serial
             , MIN(d.dbf_DT) AS first_read_dt
             , MAX(d.dbf_DT) AS last_read_dt
          FROM dbo.Database d
         WHERE d.dbf_DT > DATEADD(HH, -24, GETDATE()
         GROUP BY d.serial
       ) s
  JOIN dbo.Database fr
    ON fr.serial = s.serial 
   AND fr.dbf_DT = s.first_read_dt
  JOIN dbo.Database lr
    ON lr.serial = s.serial 
   AND lr.dbf_DT = s.last_read_dt
 GROUP
    BY s.serial
```

(The MIN and MAX aggregates are not required if there's a guarantee the dbf_Dt will be unique for a given serial. If there's a unique constraint on (serial,dbf_DT), then the MIN and MAX can be removed, they are there only to discriminate in the event there is more than one row with a matching first_read_dt or last_read_dt.

Another approach would be to use analytic functions available in SQL Server to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to sum up the differences between each reading, then you can do it using a Common Table Expression and a Windowing function (SQL Server 2012) or Row_Number(). Both of these result in the answer of 9 gallons. See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d391/23) for working example.

```
WITH WaterFlow AS (
SELECT 
 serial,
 a.amount_read - LAG(a.amount_read) OVER(PARTITION BY a.serial ORDER BY a.date_read ASC) AS gallons             
FROM useage a
WHERE date_read > DATEADD(HH, -24, getdate())  
)
SELECT 
 serial as account,
 SUM(gallons) AS gallons
FROM WaterFlow
GROUP BY
 serial
;
```

The above uses the LAG windowing function which lets you look at the previous row, but only works on SQL Server 2012.

```
WITH WaterFlow AS (
 SELECT 
  serial,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY serial
                           ORDER BY date_read ASC) rn,
  amount_read
 FROM useage
 WHERE date_read > DATEADD(HH, -24, getdate())
)
SELECT 
 a.serial as account,
 SUM(b.amount_read - a.amount_read) as gallons
FROM WaterFlow a
LEFT JOIN WaterFlow b ON 
 a.serial= b.serial
 AND b.rn = a.rn +1  
GROUP BY
 a.serial
;
```

The above uses a Row Number and does a self join to get the previous row and should work for SQL Server 2005 and up.